# Como importar estilos de node_modules em uma biblioteca Angular 10?

Tags: css, angular, biblioteca, style, library

Estou desenvolvendo uma biblioteca Angular 10. Esta biblioteca usa o Swiper JS como dependência. Minha biblioteca deve importar estilos css do swiper.

Eu importo estilos swiper de `node_modules` usando o `@import` do scss. Isso funciona bem usando o comando `ng test`.

Mas quando eu faço um `ng build` e importo a minha biblioteca local em meu aplicativo, recebo um erro no console javascript. O erro diz que os estilos do swiper não foram encontrados em `node_modules`.

Como devo importar os estilos css de uma biblioteca de dentro de `node_modules` para dentro de uma biblioteca Angular 10?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do arquivo **.angular-cli.json** na raiz do projeto é possível importar os arquivos css apenas mapeando cada um deles na propriedade styles, exemplo do css da biblioteca primeng:

```
{
    ...
    "apps": [
        {
            ...,
            "styles": [
                "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                "styles.scss"
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Após isso, basta executar o comando **ng build** ou **ng serve** novamente para que o css seja compilado junto ao código-fonte

Comment: Isso ai é na biblioteca ou no app? Não existe arquivo .angular-cli.json em nenhum dos dois. 
Lembrando que ambos são projetos Angular 10. Você está se referindo ao angular.json?